# Even numbers combinatorial game

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory, computer-vision

We have $2$ piles of coins-one of them with $X$ number of sheets and the other with $Y$ number of sheets, $X$ and $Y$ are larger than $0$.

$2$ players are playing against each others , every player **at his turn** chooses a pile and he is allowed to take an even number ($K$) from the coins in that pile, then he returns half of $K$ to the other pile (that he didn't choose from in this turn) and keeps the other half out of the game (you can take from different piles in different turns like you can choose now from pile $1$ and then in the next turn you can choose from pile $2$).

As the game goes the numbers $X$ and $Y$ becomes smaller.When $X$ and $Y$ are less than $2$ the game stops.The winner is the player who does the last step.

**For example:**
if in pile $1$ we have $2$ coins and in pile $2$ we have $1$ coin $(2,1)$ I shouldn't start because I would lose WHY?:
$(2,1)$-->I take $2$ from pile $1$ -->$(0,2)$ then he takes $2$ from pile $2$ and wins-->$(1,0)$ because $X$ and $Y$ are less than $2$ when my turn is about to start.

**I want a strategy which always wins, you can choose weather to start or not**
please specify your strategy and why it wins!
Thank you

Comment: I think you meant that pile one has two coins (not three) in the example. Also, I believe the final position is $(1,0)$ (not $(1,1)$).

Comment: I think it's highly dependent on position. $(2,2)$ is also losing for the starting player, because the first move is forced in the sequence $(2,2) \rightarrow (0,3) \rightarrow (1,1)$. On the other hand, $(4,1)$ is winning because you have the move $(4,1) \rightarrow (2,2)$.

Comment: yes sorry , i used a different example and changed it

Comment: no you can remove 4 then you have (0,3) which is a winning position for the enemy [(0,3) removes 2--.>(1,1)] and wins

Comment: ... which proves that you can lose this position if you want to. But it doesn't change the fact that the position itself is winning for the first player, because he has a move that wins by force.

Comment: Oh okay I get it, but when do you actually know like is there a specific pattern that I should follow in order to find out?

Comment: After experimenting a bit, I believe this variant of nim follows a simple pattern (see my answer). See also [Nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) and [Wythoff's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wythoff%27s_game).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Lemma*: $(X,Y)$ is winning for the starting player if and only if $|X - Y| > 1$.

Obs. The positions $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are losing because the player who gets them has no moves (hence the last move was made by the winner).

*Proof of the Lemma*: 
We shall prove this by induction on $X + Y$.

If $X + Y = 1$, than the statement is obviously true.
Suppose now that $X + Y = n$, and that we have shown that the statement is true for any pair $(X', Y')$ satisfying $X' + Y' < n$.

Suppose $|X - Y| \leq 1$. Without loss of generality, any move will be of the form $(X, Y) \rightarrow (X - 2k, Y + k)$, and by the triangle inequality we have $|X - 2k - (Y + k)| = |X - Y - 3k| \geq 3k - |X - Y| \geq 2$. By induction, the resulting position is winning (hence the starting position has to be losing).

Suppose now $|X - Y| \geq 2$, and suppose without loss of generality that $X \geq Y$. Set $k = \left\lfloor \frac{X - Y + 1}{3} \right\rfloor$, and consider the position $(X - 2k, Y + k)$ which is one move away from our starting position.

It should be clear that 
$$ (X - Y + 1) - 2 = X - Y - 1 \leq 3k \leq X - Y + 1,$$ 
hence 
$$X - Y - (X - Y + 1) = -1 \leq X - Y - 3k \leq 1 = X - Y - (X - Y -1).$$

Therefore, $|X - 2k - (Y + k)| = |X - Y - 3k| \leq 1$, which implies that the position $(X - 2k, Y + k)$ is losing. The proof is complete.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say that (1,0) and (0,1) are obviously losing positions since the next player has no moves. But then you claim that "winning position if the heap sizes are close" is obviously true for heap sizes that sum to 1. This seems contradictory to me.

Comment: @MarkS. The statement of the lemma was wrong (but the proof was correct). I've edited this, thanks for pointing It out.